# Why do I get a new session when I refresh the page (I created session after save())

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express

I thought session was to keep information on the user users computer untill it expires or I destroy it. what I want to do is, if the user is anonymous create an id for him, put it in the session and where every he goes on the site or clicks I could store stuff in a DB record belonging to the anonymous user by the id.

I use a middleware to check if the the user logged in with passport on every rout and if he didn't I want to create `req.session.anon`. I assigned `req.session.anon` to the ObjectId that was created when I save the anon(see code). The second time(page refresh) the user should have a session.anon id so this check should fail `}else if(!req.session.anon){` but it doesn't and I create another record with a new ID.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    // console.log("req.user ::::  ", req.user.local.username)
    if(req.user){
        app.locals.userid = req.user._id;
        app.locals.username = req.user.local.username;
        console.log("req.user is there")
    }else if(!req.session.anon){
        var anon = new Anon()
        anon.save(function(err, data){
            console.log(data)
            req.session.anon = data._id

            console.log("req.session.anon " , req.session.anon);// prints out the ID
        })               
    }
    next();
});
```

session set up

```
app.use(session({secret : "thisisastring",
                        saveUninitialized : true,
                        resave : true
}));
```

EDIT Im think now it has something to do with setting `req.session.anon = data._id` in the call back. but req.session is set from the console

Comment: Which `session` library are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a sequencing problem.  I'm not sure this is causing your session issue, but it is definitely not correct the way you are doing it.

`anon.save()` appears to be asynchronous.  That means it finishes some time LATER and calls its callback then.  But, you are calling `next()` before that.  So, that means that `req.session.anon` will not be in place when `next()` is called which means that subsequent handlers for this request will not see the value of `req.session.anon`.  Probably, the auto resave happens before you have added `req.session.anon` and thus it doesn't get saved.

You can fix that issue like this:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    // console.log("req.user ::::  ", req.user.local.username)
    if(req.user){
        app.locals.userid = req.user._id;
        app.locals.username = req.user.local.username;
        console.log("req.user is there")
        next();
    }else if(!req.session.anon){
        var anon = new Anon()
        anon.save(function(err, data){
            console.log(data)
            req.session.anon = data._id

            console.log("req.session.anon " , req.session.anon);// prints out the ID
            next();
        })               
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

This waits to call `next()` until after you have updated the session.

---

Because your use of the `resave` feature is deprecated, it may also make sense for you to manually save your session after modifying it:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    // console.log("req.user ::::  ", req.user.local.username)
    if(req.user){
        app.locals.userid = req.user._id;
        app.locals.username = req.user.local.username;
        console.log("req.user is there")
        next();
    }else if(!req.session.anon){
        var anon = new Anon()
        anon.save(function(err, data){
            console.log(data)
            req.session.anon = data._id;
            req.session.save(function() {
                console.log("req.session.anon " , req.session.anon);// prints out the ID
                next();
            });
        });
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The session is typically associated to the browser through a cookie.

Use fiddler to see if the session cookie is written to the response stream and that the cookie is being sent back with the next requests.

Maybe you need to move the next() within the initial if clause and to the bottom of the else..save callback method to ensure that session is attached to the response before it is closed.

Comment: I never used fiddler. Ill look into it later. I don't know if your way will help me. but I want to say that if i put `console.log("Outside. req.session.anon " , req.session.anon);` outside the `if else` I get `Outside. req.session.anon  undefined` in the console so It looks like it is not being defined in the scope.

Comment: the save callback is async and next() might be called prior to setting anon on the session

Comment: I think I see some improvements It only saves the anon user once now. I put `next()` in the `if` and  in the `if else` .  I also had to make an `else` and put a `next()` in there so the spinning icon in the tab of the page would stop spinning. Is that what you recommended? Does it sound good? Thanks.